# How to group by column on one side of many to many, and be able to .each through matches on other side

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 tables, events, games, eventgames(joins the others). I am trying to create a page that lists each event, with each game that is going to be at the event. The page is currently working, but is making a new DB query for every row on the HTML table. I'm sending @events = Event.all from the controller and accessing the info this way.

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/events/<%= event.id %>"><%= event.title %></a></td>
        <td><a href="/users/<%= event.user.id %>"><%= event.user.username %></a></td>
        <td><%= event.description %></td>
        <td>
        <% event.games.each do |game| %>
            <a href='/games/<%= game.id %>'><%= game.name %></a> 
        <% end %>
        </td>
```

I attempted to change what is sent from the controller by making a new query that includes all the info. It's not quite working how I intended, the problem is that when i do @events.each events are repeated by however many games are going to be there.

```
@events = Event.joins("LEFT JOIN eventgames ON events.id = eventgames.event_id")
.select("events.*")
.group("events.id")
.joins("LEFT JOIN games ON eventgames.game_id = games.id")
.select("games.id as gameid, games.name")
.group("games.id")
```

I tried, but obviously my grouping is not correct. How would I go about grouping it so there is only 1 event per event ID, while also being able to iterate through the games attached to the event?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, instead of `@events = Event.all`, try the following:

```
@events = Event.inclues(:games).all
```

Refer to [ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#includes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-includes) for more info.

Also, it is always a good idea to limit the number of `@events` you want to load, either through `where` conditions or at least by pagination.